# Azure DevOps pipeline to Dynamics365 CRM-CLI Error

Tags: git, azure-devops, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am new to Azure DevOps and want to build a pipeline that migrates and deploys the CRM solution from dev env to production env. I followed this tutorial [Build Azure DevOps Pipelines for Dynamics 365 CRM/Power Platform](https://pooja-bhardwaj.medium.com/automate-solution-deployment-for-dynamics-365-power-platform-using-azure-pipelines-part-1-df547c4695a4).
When it reaches the CLI command it stops and an error appears as shown in the following image ([Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF9ZO.png)).
the CLI command is as shown below:

```
echo commit all changes
git config user.email “Email@Email”
git config user.name “Automatic Build”
git checkout master
git add --all
git commit -m “solution export”
echo push code to new repo
git -c http.extraheader=”AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)” push origin master
```

this is the Solution OutPut File in "Power Platform Export Solution":

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(SolutionName)_managed.zip
```

this is the Power Platform Unpack Solution :

Solution Input File

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(SolutionName)_managed.zip
```

Target Folder to Unpack Solution

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(SolutionName)_managed
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may not have a branch called master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue: error: `pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git` is caused by the command `git checkout master`. In the Azure DevOps, the default branch name has been changed to **main** instead of **master**. We could see it in the repo->branch or build definition, check the pic below.

[image]

We need to change the branch name to main or other existing branch names.

For example:

```
git checkout main
```

Result:

[image]